# Applying ratelimit decorator to auth views.py

Tags: django

I want to rate limit several views in my Django app (login, register_account, password reset, ...). I am already using Django-Ratelimit. But I am unsure how to add this decorator to existing views. Writing my own views and using them in a custom urls.py looks like a lot of boilerplate code just to add some decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use decorators directly in your urls.

```
url(r'^login/$', ratelimit(key='whatever')(login_func), name='login'),
```